# Reputation out of sync (upvote not counted)

Tags: bug, reputation

The reputation displayed in [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/785541/wladimir-palant) and on https://stackoverflow.com/reputation were the same for quite a while already - the changes to the reputation system worked out well. Still, something went wrong today. First I noticed that the indicator on the "reputation" tab mentioned 15 points reputation increase when I really gained 25 points:

[image: screenshot1]

[image: screenshot2]

I then checked the total reputation and there is a 10 points mismatch here as well:

[image: screenshot3]

[image: screenshot4]

I guess that triggering a reputation recalc will fix this - but this still might be a bug worth looking into. Unfortunately, I have no idea what triggered it. From what I can tell, it was an absolutely normal upvote that didn't get counted for some reason.

**Edit**: I'm pretty certain that my total reputation was 15434 this morning - my [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/412463/wladimir-palant?tab=reputation) however claims that it was 15424. So maybe the issue is with the 10 points I received yesterday, the display in the network profile doesn't show them for some reason.

Comment: The network profile is only synced once every 24 hours. It is not live.

Comment: @Oded: I know. Which is why I point out the mismatch for *yesterday's* reputation (the network profile is synced at 1 AM local time).

Comment: @Oded: That's synced relatively constantly, it's done via the aggregator that relays every rep change up to a central database via redis messaging.  SE may cache for a while on top of querying that database, but nowhere near a day.

Comment: Its caching.  Its always caching.  Unless its a race condition.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This happens because of how Linq2SQL works, and it really, *really* sucks but there's little we can do about it without a *major* overhaul (getting off Linq2SQL for this, which we have considered, and continue to).  So here's how it goes:

Let's assume you're at 100 rep before this happens, to keep it simple.

- OP upvotes your answer, request sent to the server, in progress...
- OP accepts your answer, request sent to server, in progress...
- Upvote request gets your user object (**100** reputation)...
- Accept vote request gets your user object (**100** reputation)...
- Upvote passes through logic/checks, etc, determines you get 10 points... **110** reputation
- Accept vote passes through similar logic, determines you get 15 points... **115** reputation ***RUH ROH***
- Upvote saves, in the form of `Update Users Set Reputation = 110 Where UserId = @Id`
- Accept vote saves, in the form of `Update Users Set Reputation = 115 Where UserId = @Id`
- You now have 115, not 125.

....you see where the problem is here.  Since Linq does a `=` and we can't make Linq2SQL do a `Reputation = Reputation + @delta` format...last save wins in this kind of race.

The good news is that the reputation history view that tracks *every* change does not suffer this problem...since it's just inserting 2 rows (in there your summation of rep is what it should be).  This allows us to compared, detect and fix up these race results every night, so there's a job to do that until we go nuts and rewrite how rep is saved (it would touch a *lot* of code).

Comment: So the answer is don't accept immediately after upvoting (and vice versa). :)

Comment: Ok, so there is a classical race condition and I simply didn't see it on this site before. Thank you for the detailed explanation. I made sure to put a little wait between upvoting and accepting your answer :)

Comment: @WladimirPalant - yup it is a rare one (may happen on different web servers, etc), but has to happen *very* fast...we only see about 20-50 of these a day total last I looked a week ago.